# How to update to the latest external Git in Azure Web App?

Tags: azure, github

Someone deployed a ChatGPT Web app in Azure for me, but the version installed from the repository is from a few months ago. I'm trying to figure out how to update the external Git, but if I reconnect it, the whole app breaks (I get a 500 error).

[image]